# Creating CPU/GPU/Memory load average history

Tags: memory, nvidia, cpu, load

In our research group we are running a computing server for deep learning with a number of NVIDIA Titan X graphics cards and quite some CPU cores. Given that it is a research lab and we have ~10 people using the machine the load on the CPU/GPU cores is almost always high.

I am now in charge showing that the machine is overly used and I can propose hardware upgrades. To make an argument, I want to create a detailed history of the CPU/GPU/MEM usage on the machine. The problem is, I don't know the right tools for the job. Of course, I can do some scripting but I prefer off-the-shelf tools since I am not a system administrator :) For monitoring the CPU/GPU usage I typically use `nvidia-smi` and `htop`, but these are not suitable for generating long-time histories.

Any recommendations on creating such histories?

Comment: Do you mean a monitoring tool like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)?

Comment: munin indeed looks like a good solution. In the contrib directory of munin there are some plugins for monitoring GPU utilization/temperature. I will give them a try!

https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/gpu/nvidia_gpu_

Comment: There is also a plugin called `nvidia_` (for debian it is in the `munin-plugins-core` package) which should return temperature, clock speed and voltage.